# How can I generate a list of the current excel sheets to column A

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

As the title says,since it is an online, shared document it doesnt allow macros/VBA, and the only other solution I found is with name manager, define names, is also unavailable in excel online.

expected output:

A1 sheet1
A2 sheet2
A3 sheet3
A4 sheet4

Comment: you need to use office scripts, which can work online: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74878435/office-script-to-get-sheet-names-and-populate-them-in-a-column